# MVC Button is not firing ActionResult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Recently I started studiyng MVC apps, and so far I've been stuck on this.

I have this .cshtml code:

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.NewCustomerViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "NewCustomer";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>New Customer</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Customers",FormMethod.Post,null))
{

    <form class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </form>
    <form class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.Birthdate)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Customer.Birthdate, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </form>
    <form class="checkbox">
        <label>
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter, new { @class = "form-control" }) Subscribed to Newsletter
        </label>
    </form>
    <form class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipTypeId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Customer.MembershipType, new SelectList(Model.MembershipTypes, "Id", "Name"), "Select Membership Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </form>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Customer.Id)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>   
}
```

That references to this action in the CustomersControler.cs file:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(Customer customer)
        {
            if (customer.Id == 0)
                _context.Customers.Add(customer);
            else
            {
                var customerInDb = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == customer.Id);
                customerInDb.Name = customer.Name;
                customerInDb.Birthdate = customer.Birthdate;
                customerInDb.MembershipTypeId = customer.MembershipTypeId;
                customerInDb.IsSubscribedToNewsletter = customer.IsSubscribedToNewsletter;


            }

            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Customers", "Index");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I try to click the Save button, it simply doesn't fire the Save ActionResult.
I have already trying to start in debug mode and set breakpoints over the code, but it's really not firing the method.
I've read that it has something to do with a JQuery event that is been triggered before ActionResult, but I don't know what to do to stop it (if JQuery really has something to do about this)

Any ideas? Please, I'm really stuck on this!

Comment: Unrelated, but you can't nest forms inside forms, those should be `<div class='form-group'...`

Comment: Oh, thanks! Sorry for the mistake! I'm really a newbie on this topic.

Comment: What does happen? If you monitor the network tab of your browser what does clicking that button generate for a request?

Comment: It wasn't generating any request at all, it was doing literaly nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model in your view is `NewCustomerViewModel` therefore the model your binding to must be the same (or you need to use the `Prefix` property of the `BindAttribute`).

Change the signature of your method to

```
public ActionResult Save(NewCustomersViewModel model)
```

In addition you need to remove all your `<form>` elements (except the one generated by `BeginForm`) as nested forms are invalid   html.

However, your code suggests that your view model contains  a property for a `Customer` data model, which is bad practice. A view model should only contain the properties of the data model you need in the view. You then map the properties of the view model to the data model.

Comment: OMG it worked!!! Thanks man, I've implemented your tips and now that button is firing like a rocket launcher! Thank you very much!